# PostgreSQL error: remote query result rowtype does not match the specified FROM clause rowtype, on remote function call

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-9.6, remote, dblink

This is my **remote** function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public._test1()
RETURNS record
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
 rec record;
BEGIN
  select 1,2 into rec;
  return rec;
END $function$;
```

This is my **local** function call:

```
SELECT x.a, x.b
FROM dblink('conn_str', 'select public._test1();')
as x(a int ,b int);
```

This is the error thrown:

```
ERROR: remote query result rowtype does not match the specified FROM clause rowtype
```

Since DBLINK requires that I define a schema to place the function's return items, how do I make the call to recognize a `record` type being returned by the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what's going on, first check what is being done on the remote:

```
SELECT _test1();
 _test1 
────────
 (1,2)
```

This does return a record, not two integers.  When the `dblink()` call reports

```
ERROR:  remote query result rowtype does not match the specified FROM clause rowtype
```

it's because locally you defined the row type as `x(a int, b int)`, but that doesn't match the record on the remote.  The reason is that `dblink()` itself doesn't know about (as it itself has a `SETOF record` return type), therefore it cannot push this information to the remote.  So what you have to do is the following:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dblink('local', 'SELECT * FROM _test1() AS x(a int, b int)') AS t(a int, b int);

 a │ b 
───┼───
 1 │ 2
```

Specifying the record type twice seems superfluous, but if you omitted the local one, it would result in another error:

```
SELECT * FROM dblink('local', 'SELECT * FROM _test1() AS x(a int, b int)') AS t;
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM dblink('local', 'SELECT * FROM _test1() AS x(a...
                      ^
```

Omitting the remote record definition:

```
SELECT * FROM dblink('local', 'SELECT * FROM _test1() ') AS t(a int, b int);
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
CONTEXT:  Error occurred on dblink connection named "local": could not execute query.
```

(The difference in the error message shows this time the problem is on the remote side.)

One ore thing that is different in my version is `SELECT * FROM _test()`.  See what happens when you call the function in the `SELECT` list instead of the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM dblink('local', 'SELECT _test1() AS x(a int, b int)') AS t(a int, b int);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
CONTEXT:  Error occurred on dblink connection named "local": could not execute query.
```

You can make this nicer if you created the remote function as `RETURNS TABLE` (or, equivalently, define `OUT` arguments there):

```
-- on the remote
CREATE FUNCTION bla() 
    RETURNS TABLE (a int, b int) LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
    SELECT 1, 2
$$;


SELECT * FROM dblink('local', 'SELECT * FROM bla() ') AS t(a int, b int);
 a │ b 
───┼───
 1 │ 2
```

The `record` type is designed to be flexible, but it comes at a price.  You cannot avoid paying this price with `dblink()`, though, as it has to be able to accommodate any return type.

Answer (score 2):

In my scenario, I get exactly the same error.

> ERROR: remote query result rowtype does not match the specified FROM
> clause rowtype

I have a VIEW using dblink and initially I create a VIEW using "SELECT *" and it works fine, but after a while my queries started to fail.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.my_table
 AS
 SELECT remote_data.field1, remote_data.field2, remote_data.field3
FROM dblink('hostaddr=<IP> port=<port> dbname=<my_db> user=<user> password=<pass>'::text,
'SELECT * FROM public.one_table::text) AS remote_data(field1 bigint, field2 text, field3 date);
```

During the investigation, I realized that the error is related to the order of the fields in the SELECT statement.

So I changed the "SELECT *" to "SELECT field1, field2, field3 ..." and my queries using this VIEW are ok.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.my_table
 AS
 SELECT remote_data.field1, remote_data.field2, remote_data.field3
FROM dblink('hostaddr=<IP> port=<port> dbname=<my_db> user=<user> password=<pass>'::text,
'SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM public.one_table::text) AS remote_data(field1 bigint, field2 text, field3 date);
```

Comment: This answer worked for me without exposing twice the data format.